# Next.js couldn't find generated CSS files in _next directory

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, next.js

Components are imported `scss` files directly. My `next.config.js` looks like this:

```
webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
  ...
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
        },
      },
      'sass-loader',
    ],
  });
  ...
  config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin());
},
```

After attempting to load the generated CSS, located in the `_next` directory I've got a `404` error:

[image]

I'm also using dynamic routing, that's why the URL got `[]` in it.

Comment: Rather than manually configuring the webpack config, have you tried using [Next.js built-in SASS support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support)?